# Independent control of display scale

Tags: multi-monitor, display, displaylink

Just got my first Librem laptop and trying to figure out how to set it up with my two 34in 4K displays... I was able to get one of them working by setting up a custom modeline with `xrandr` and creating a config file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

One external display now works with full resolution (3440x1440) on the HDMI-1 port.

However, since the internal display is also 4K (but physically much smaller), the internal display can not be used at 100% scale.
Meanwhile, the external display does need to be at 100% scale or it's a waste of screen (everything looks too large).

Presently, if I adjust the scale in Display Settings (GUI), both displays change their scale. I am trying to figure out how to control display scale independently for each available display.

In addition, I would also like to figure out how to display to my second external display over either USB C or USB 2.0...

PureOS is Debian based, and I am using Xorg.

Comment: 3440 x 1440 is UWQHD ...... 3840 × 2160 is 4K